# All text appearing in italics in PDF output

Tags: italic

Suddenly, all my text that should be normal text form is appearing as italics text in my PDF. How to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without a code reproducing the problem, how could anyone guess?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! this can't happen without some instruction in your document code.

Comment: Could it be that you are in math mode?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. As marmot also just commented, you could have an unmatched dollar sign, meaning you are still in math mode. I suggest to read some introductory material, that will make you see such simple things with ease.

Comment: Another possibility is that you may have used a font declaration instead of a text-block command. For example `\em{text}` instead of `\emph{text}`.

Comment: If you think that the code will work well in other's computer, you should also attach a screenshot showing the problem in additional to your code.

Comment: Bandle of to all of you for your valuable suggestions. I read the code thoroughly and found I mistakenly type lemma command. My latex file was quite big that's why it takes time to find the mistake,